# Route to php file in Ktor

Tags: php, html, kotlin, routes, ktor

I have previously created a website in xampp and want to migrate the files to a ktor project. I have reviewed a number of examples in routing ktor to html pages and have seen this work. Is there a way to route to a php file and have this also display as it would through xampp. I have the below code in my ktor project. When i navigate to localhost:8080/website/form/index.php i am redirected to localhost:8080/website/form/index.phtml. The webpage isn't shown but the file index.php is then downloaded with the error. Am i thinking about this in the wrong way.

```
route("/website"){     
  static("form"){
            resources("static")
            file("index.php")
    }
}
```

This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/itinerary/form/index.phml

HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: routimg a request to a php file would statically serve it as ktor is not capable of running php code.

Answer (score 0):

With your routing configuration, the file `index.php` should be located in the working directory to be served.

To solve your problem you can execute a process with the PHP interpreter for each request and respond with result content. Please note that this solution is not efficient and not robust. Here is an example:

```
routing {
    route("/website") {
        route("/form") {
            get("index.php") {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val process = ProcessBuilder().command("/usr/bin/env", "php", "-f", "index.php").start()
                    process.waitFor()
                    call.respondBytes(process.inputStream.readAllBytes(), contentType = ContentType.Text.Html)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```